# Considering HTTP headers when tracking users pagevisit with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, http, server-side

Let's say you are not using a javascript and would like to track each visitor/pageviews directly from your PHP script. Bots are not easy to track. They don't send a standard http header. Server-side coders must consider and filter too many http headers. For example Facebook. When we have got a visit which contains `X-Purpose: preview` this means facebook is fetching your url to show to user faster. Same applies for Safari and Chrome. I simply send `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` to fetching requests. Here is the code i have written and added to the top of my php files for this:

```
$xpurpose = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PURPOSE'];
$xmoz = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_MOZ'];
$liger = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FB_HTTP_ENGINE'];

if (($liger == "Liger" || $liger == "Tigon+iOS") && $xpurpose == "preview") {
    header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
    echo("403: Forbidden");
    exit();
}
```

Facebook sends **Liger** for it's Android FB App and **Tigon+iOS** for iPhone. Here is the link for more information about Facebook's headers:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1514372351922333

And more links:
http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/magento-website-hammering-facebook-liger/
http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/mitigating-facebook-x-fb-http-engine-liger/

`HTTP_X_MOZ` tag usually used by Chrome and Safari.

I have been having trouble for months. However, i believe there are more like them. For example Google. I am not 100% sure what tags Google and other providers send.

My question is; do you know any known tags to consider and exclude? If you don't want to chose to use JS and etc., what is the best way to track users?

Comment: Thanks. I was getting pounded by Liger over the last few days. Capturing request headers I could confirm Liger and 'preview' and added the 403 via PHP header, worked like a charm. Thanks!